# what is Mongoclient and what is its purpose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

what is Mongoclient ? What does it do in the following statement?

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
```

Comment: You might check this out to figure it out: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/

Answer (score 4):

MongoClient in your example is just a Nodejs library that handles connecting to and interacting with a MongoDB database.

Answer (score 1):

```
//This is A Better Way To Write It (ES6 Version)
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');
//You Can Also Include Multiple Methods From mongo like this
const {MongoClient, ObjectID} = require('mongodb');
```

It Is A NodeJs Module That Lets You Manipulate,Create,Connect To A Mongo Database.